# Populating a standard .net 2.0 GridView / TreeView control using XML from a database as opposed to an XML file

Tags: xml, gridview, .net-2.0, treeview, xslt

At present I am populating a standard .net 2.0 GridView & TreeView control using a physical XML document which uses an XSLT stylesheet. But i need to make the population of the grid more dynamic, while still using the XSLT style sheet

Does anyone know if it is possible to populate a standard .net 2.0 Gridview & TreeView control another way apart from using an a physical XML document?

I currently have some XML code stored in a database. Can i retreive it from the databe, apply XSLT style sheet on it and pass it onto the grid /  tree without having to make a physical file?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean when you say "more dynamic". What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: Are you using an XmlDataSource?

Comment: XmlDataSource is being used at the moment but it uses a physical xml file saved on the machine. I have a source which gives out the XML in the form of a datastream. I need to use this xml stream direct or using a variable which could store the XML and not have to use a physical file.

Comment: So what is this 'datastream'? Is it an XmlReader or Stream type source?

Comment: its a stream type source... where i can save the xml code block onto a variable and preferable use the value in the variable to populate the grid..

Comment: Ok....so what do you do with the xml stream at the moment? A code example would be good

Comment: i guess what i basically want to know is whether i can populate a grid using XML stored in databe without having to create a physical XML file.

Comment: Ok....how are you getting the xml from the datastream to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an XmlDataSource you can set the Data property to any block of Xml.  For example you could have a method which calls a webservice, returns some Xml, performs a transform and then assigns to the Data property.  Calling DataBind on your grid will then update.  It is important to note that if you have a value set in the DataFile property then this will always take precedence over anything you specify for Data.

You can use the exact same approach to retrieve some Xml from your database, transform and assign to XmldataSource.Data

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that... that was exactly what i needed... I didnt realise i could use the "Data" property of the XmldataSource instead of the "DataFile" property... Sorry I'm a total novice at this!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use XML to populate a `GridView` by using the [`XmlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx) control. The following links should get you started:

> [XmlDataSource Web Server Control Overview (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494y92bs.aspx)
>
> [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Accessing Data with the DataSource Controls (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479341.aspx)
>
> [ASP.NET Quickstart Tutorials - XmlDataSource](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/xmldatasource.aspx)

The last link doesn't specifically cover binding a `GridView` to the `XmlDataSource` but does provide some useful reference code. You may need to transform your source XML to a format that the `GridView` can make sense of.